# Allocating, Deallocating and memory management on Windows with breakpoints set

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management

I have a C++ application with a very strange phenomenon.

I'm running my application on a large input, and I have many buffers that are allocated and de-allocated during run-time.

For input that it large enough, I have allocation error, meaning out of memory.

But, when I put a breakpoint on each allocation, and then run from allocation to allocation, my application won't crash.

My assumption that it has to be something related to the way windows XP manages the memory.
Is anyone has an idea what can cause this phenomenon, and how to over come it?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you are running out of memory? how did you check this? is `new` throwing `bad_alloc` exception?

Comment: Note that the memory manager [behaves differently depending on whether you are running with a debugger or not](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff538841.aspx). Set `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1` to force the non-debug heap to be used even if a debugger is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frequent allocation and deallocation can lead to memory fragmentation. My guess is that, when you step through the program with a debugger, it gives the OS idle-time to defragment the memory. To avoid the problem when running your program normally, you should consider memory/object-pool (see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/pool/doc/html/index.html) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern)).

Comment: Yes, I also suspect it is the reason. Is there a way to diagnose it?

Comment: I thought all modern OSes use memory paging and fragmentation does not cause allocation denial. Am I wrong?

Comment: Windows does not defragment process' virtual address space behind the scenes. It wouldn't know how to do it correctly without breaking the process.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: These techniques can delay the problem, but at some point (worst case then the address-space is exhausted, unlikely on 64bit systems though) it can still happen that the system cannot find a continuous block large enough to satisfy a request.

Comment: @Alex: As I said, it was just a guess - seems I was wrong then.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: but you're right about the possibility of delaying the problem because of the program being idle in the debugger. Also, there could be memory leaks.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: But that's the whole point of paging! You don't neeed a _continuous_ block anymore!

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: Could you show me some reference where this is explained? I have never heard of that before.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: looks like I have chosen a wrong word. I meant paged memory, page tables etc.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: I know what paging is, the word was right. But I have never heard that paging can be used to map a non-continuous memory-range to a continuous one.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: Sorry, I was wrong. What I was referring to concerns physical memory (where paging allows to overcome fragmentation), but the virtual memory itself is still succeptible to fragmentation since there is no virtual virtual memory.

Comment: I think it was a memory fragmentation. I overcame this problem by reducing the number of times those large buffers were allocated - now my app won't crash.

Answer (score 0):

Application behavior is different in Release and Debug runs. As you are Saying in normal run it gives Out of Memory there is some thing wrong with your code. It may be saying there is no memory or no continuous memory.

You can use some static or dynamic code analyses to find out the problem.
IBM Purifier( Trial version)

Comment: Actually, I ran it in debug mode, even without the breakpoints. So I don't think it is related to Debug/Realse runs.